# Button listeners in a quiz - the old listeners produce wrong output

Tags: javascript, jquery

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/knm81zL2/

I have a quiz like this:

[image]

When it's the first question there is just one listener on each button and clicking the wrong buttons doesn't produce the `Well done` alert or enables the Next button:

[image]

However when I go to the next question:

[image]

[image]

Clicking the previously correct `Whale` button would result in `Well done` alert and the Next button becomes enabled:

[image]

Clicking on the `Monkey` button does the same + makes the `Monkey` button green:

[image]

```
<H4><span id="question-number">Question </span></H4>
<H4><span id="question-text">Question </span></H4>

<table class="selection">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='choices'>
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">A</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='choices' >
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">B</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='choices' >
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">C</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='choices' >
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">D</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='choices'>
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">E</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='choices'>
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">F</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class='choices'>
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">G</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='choices'>
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">H</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class='choices'>
                <button class="btnclass" type="button">K</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>

<button id="next-button" type="button">Next</button>
```

```
var questions = [
    [
        "Biggets animal", ["Cat", "Dog", "Monkey",
        "Bear", "Whale", "Crocodile",
        "Wolverine", "Dragon", "Pigeon"],
        "Whale"],

    ["Smartest animal", ["Cat", "Dog", "Monkey",
        "Bear", "Whale", "Crocodile",
        "Wolverine", "Dragon", "Pigeon"],
        "Monkey"],

    ["Angriest animal", ["Cat", "Dog", "Monkey",
        "Bear", "Whale", "Crocodile",
        "Wolverine", "Dragon", "Pigeon"],
        "Wolverine"]

];

var k = 0;


var choiceElements = $('#question-number');
var questionTextElement = $('#question-text');
var nextButton = $('#next-button');


var questionCorrect = "F";

var choiceElements = $('.choices');

// questions.forEach(function(question)  {
showQuestion(k, questions[k], questions);

// });


function showQuestion(k, question, questions) {
    nextButton.prop("disabled", true);

    var questionText = question[0];
    // alert(questionText);
    var questionChoices = question[1];
    var questionCorrect = question[2];

    questionTextElement.html(questionText);


    for (var i = 0; i < choiceElements.length; i++) {
        nextButton.prop("disabled", true);
        var buttonElement = $("button", choiceElements[i]);
        buttonElement.html(questionChoices[i])

        buttonElement.on("click", function (event) {

            if ($(this).text() === questionCorrect) {
                console.log("this text: " + $(this).text());
                console.log("question correct: " + questionCorrect);
                $(this).css("background-color", "green");
                alert("well done");
                nextButton.prop("disabled", false);
            } else {
                $(this).css("background-color", "red");
                console.log($(this).html() + " clicked");
                //  $(this).prop("disabled", true);

            }
        });
    }


}

nextButton.on("click", function (event) {
    k++;
    showQuestion(k, questions[k], questions);

    for (var i = 0; i < choiceElements.length; i++) {
        var buttonElement = $("button", choiceElements[i]);
        buttonElement.css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
});
```

How do I fix this? What is a good-practice approach for a problem like mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow remove/reset the listeners set in the last iteration. I'd call `.off('click')` before attaching the new click listener in `showQuestion`:

```
buttonElement.off('click').on("click", function(event) {
```

```js
var questions = [
  [
    "Biggets animal", ["Cat", "Dog", "Monkey",
      "Bear", "Whale", "Crocodile",
      "Wolverine", "Dragon", "Pigeon"
    ],
    "Whale"
  ],

  ["Smartest animal", ["Cat", "Dog", "Monkey",
      "Bear", "Whale", "Crocodile",
      "Wolverine", "Dragon", "Pigeon"
    ],
    "Monkey"
  ],

  ["Angriest animal", ["Cat", "Dog", "Monkey",
      "Bear", "Whale", "Crocodile",
      "Wolverine", "Dragon", "Pigeon"
    ],
    "Wolverine"
  ]

];

var k = 0;


var choiceElements = $('#question-number');
var questionTextElement = $('#question-text');
var nextButton = $('#next-button');



var questionCorrect = "F";

var choiceElements = $('.choices');

// questions.forEach(function(question)  {
showQuestion(k, questions[k], questions);
// });


function showQuestion(k, question, questions) {
  nextButton.prop("disabled", true);

  var questionText = question[0];
  // alert(questionText);
  var questionChoices = question[1];
  var questionCorrect = question[2];

  questionTextElement.html(questionText);


  for (var i = 0; i < choiceElements.length; i++) {
    nextButton.prop("disabled", true);
    var buttonElement = $("button", choiceElements[i]);
    buttonElement.html(questionChoices[i])

    buttonElement.off('click').on("click", function(event) {

      if ($(this).text() === questionCorrect) {
        console.log("this text: " + $(this).text());
        console.log("question correct: " + questionCorrect);
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
        alert("well done");
        nextButton.prop("disabled", false);
      } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        console.log($(this).html() + " clicked");
        //  $(this).prop("disabled", true);

      }
    });
  }



}

nextButton.on("click", function(event) {
  k++;
  showQuestion(k, questions[k], questions);

  for (var i = 0; i < choiceElements.length; i++) {
    var buttonElement = $("button", choiceElements[i]);
    buttonElement.css("background-color", "transparent");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<H4><span id="question-number">Question </span></H4>
<H4><span id="question-text">Question </span></H4>

<table class="selection">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">A</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">B</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">C</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">D</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">E</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">F</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">G</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">H</button>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='choices'>
        <button class="btnclass" type="button">K</button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="next-button" type="button">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So the `.off()` method removes any listeners that correspond to the passed string? That's very simple! I'm not going back to plain JS after this!

Answer (score 1):

Resetting listeners is one approach, a different one would be to set some variable that stores the number/index of a current question. Then each of the buttons, when clicked, would check if it has the right answer to that question and then choose what to do (Success alert and moving to next question or not). No listener update needed, one variable to set, two to check.

Comment: Isn't it what the listener do already? How would it look in code? It looks like when the listener is set, it uses the old values of the button's text, without executing the listener's code from scratch all over again. Would your approach result in redoing the calculations?

Comment: I'd suggest you moved the listener setting out of the showQuestion function. Add listeners once, let them operate on data that changes. The goal is to have a "single source of thruth" and let everything else change as little as possible based on this source's state.